# Android - Get user picture profile URL from facebook SDK 3

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using facebook sdk 3. I would like to get the user profile image URL. How get it?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you solve it? I want image url, too. Thank.

Answer (score 1):

This is the link i use:

```
"http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=large"
```

where id is the facebook user id.

Comment: Nice! But I need to get the URL, Do you know how get it? thx!!